# django-notification: How many observed items

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-notification

I have a queryset at the moment that returns the number items in a model ordered by the number of people watching it. So I have a m2m field representing this link.

Ie:

```
#models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
...
watchers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

I would count the number of occurrences and order them by count in a default manager which was then used by the view.

Now I'm going over to using [django-notification](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/), using 'notification.ObservedItem' to allow users to watch an instance if MyModel.

So in my view when a user posts some content I have something like this:

```
notification.observe(object, request.user, 'new_object')
```

This works well.

Now, how can I generate a queryset representing all the objects of class MyModel, ordered by the number of people 'observing' them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Count
MyModel.objects.annotate(num_users=Count('watchers')).order_by('num_users')
```

Comment: You're right, I think the annotation should happen on MyModel instead, editing answer.

Comment: Holy smoke you're right. I'm confused why the documentation says you can't do it when it seems like you can.

Comment: FWIW, I tested my code with your first model implementation (watchers being a M2M) and worked well :)

Comment: Yeah I had it working with the standard m2m, but that was before the transition to django-notification.

Comment: Ah, didn't know you removed the m2m. In that case I guess you have two choices: bring back the m2m and attach a signal handler to `observe' that adds the user instance to it, or try django-generic-aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that django-notification uses generic foreign keys.

So I've redefined my watchers field:

```
watchers = generic.GenericRelation(notification.ObservedItem)
```

Then I can get all the watchers for a specific instance of MyModel.

```
$x = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
$x.watchers.all()
$[<ObservedItem: ObservedItem object>, <ObservedItem: ObservedItem object>, <ObservedItem: ObservedItem object>]
$x.watchers.count()
$3
```

Close but no cigar. I wanted to do was something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(count=Count('watchers')).order_by('count')
```

Which is something that Django can't do, [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-and-aggregation).

> Django's database aggregation API doesn't work with a GenericRelation.

Not to worry, I think this will probably help:

http://charlesleifer.com/blog/generating-aggregate-data-across-generic-relations/

Repo is here:

https://github.com/coleifer/django-generic-aggregation

I've not tried it out yet...